# How to reduce icon size of Nativescript BottomNavigation Tab

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to reduce size of icon of each tab in NativeScript BottomNavigation. below is part of my HTML

```html
      <TabStrip  iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal" >
        <TabStripItem horizontalAlignment='center' iconSource="res://home_tab" iconClass="img" >
            <Label text='Home'></Label>
            <Image src="res://home_tab" class="img" ></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem >
            <Label text='Garage'></Label>
            <Image src="res://home_tab" class="img" ></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem >
            <Label text='Account'></Label>
            <Image src="res://home_tab" class="img"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>

<style  scoped>
    .img {
      height: 5;
      width: 5;
     }

    TabStrip{
     background-color: #001A31;
     height: 83;
     padding-top: 23;
    }

    TabStripItem{
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     margin-top: 5;
     background-color: blue;
    }

    Label {
     color:white;
     font-size: 13;
    }

</style>
```

[image]

But it doesn't reduce the size of icon, And I can change size of my label text. Please help.

Comment: can you try <Label text='Home' fontSize=13></Label> and   <Image src="res://home_tab" class="img" stretch="none></Image> "

Answer (score 1):

try to provide isIconSizeFixed which has default true

```
<TabStrip iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal" isIconSizeFixed="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resource images are getting their correct sized versions from device properties.**

You better use `<Image src="res://home_tab" height="5" width="5" stretch="none" />`

---

Check docs for **ImageSource module** in

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/image-resources#loading-icons-in-the-tabview-from-the-resources

Comment: It seems nativescript does not allow to size icon in tabs. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5698